# Even if Anaconda deleted Path still indicates Anaconda is still there

Tags: python, anaconda

[image]So recently I delete anaconda from my Mac following the official guide (i.e. `rm -rf ~/anaconda`).

Unfortunately whenever I type `echo $PATH` I still get `/Applications/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

For context: Currently I am learning to code with Python following the book 'Automate the boring stuff with Python'. As I was unable to run my python scripts from my terminal I figured it may be because I use 'Anaconda' instead of the recommended 'MuEditor'(or something similar). Currently I deleted (or tried to) all versions of python from my Mac that I have installed and plan to reinstall when I found a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my opinion, that's not an issue. But if you want to delete it anyway, open `~/.bashrc` file and delete the anaconda path

Answer (score 0):

You answer lies in bash pofile file. edit the  `~/.bash_profile` and remove the anaconda directory from your PATH environment variable

if you are using bash, be sure to check your `~/.bashrc` if you don't find the PATH modified in `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I am unsure how to do so. When I type: ~/.bash_profile I get 'permission denied'. So I add 'sudo' in front. Then I get .bash_profile: command not found

Comment: 1). Change directory to your home folder. cd ~/
2). sudo nano .bash_profile

Comment: This seems to work! Still I am not sure how to proceed from now. 
Do I have to execute this line? And if yes, how? This is my first time operating the terminal so I am really not sure what to do. The help is much appreciated!
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Comment: Can you please up vote my answer? Well when you install python 3.8 there is an option to include in the path. Now you want to manually install the python3.8 in the bash_profile? if you are new to terminal my suggestion is to reinstall python using the GUI

Comment: Did upvote already, but since I don't have enough reputation now it's not publicly displayed. 
I guess I need to change the Path but I am unsure how to do so exactly. 
What do you mean with GUI?

Comment: Use thi tutorial to install python

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-macos

Comment: I still don't understand how to follow your first instructions.

Comment: Hi I'm confused now do you want to install python again? Above code is to remove the anaconda path and from the above link you can see the instruction to install python.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to do what you indicated in the first placed:

edit the  ~/.bash_profile and remove the anaconda directory from your PATH environment variable

But I am not sure what to do after I enter sudo nano .bash_prifle

Comment: Ahhh!!! Search for the path variable and remove "/Applications/anaconda3/bin:" from the found variable. and save it. to save put control + x and it will prompt to save say yes to that. and good to go.

Comment: I added a picture to indicate what I can see right now. As there are multiple entries with '/Applications/anaconda3/bin:' I am not sure what to remove.

Comment: Remove everything and FYI # in the beginning of the line is indicating that line is commented.

Comment: I deleted everything in .bash_profile and it seems to work! Thank you very much!